PowerBI how to show 1 type of value from a column that has many different values in a gauge chart?
I am new to Power Bi .
I have a column in excel which has a total of 300 rows. 100 of each of the following red, green, and blue.
I want to create 3 gauge charts to show these numbers for each values.
How can I do this without creating new columns with each different colour. is there a filter i can use ? or formula?

It would help to show an example of how you expect it to look. Preferably with sample data (markdown table), so it's reproducable.

Once you have your gauge chart created with the desired values, you can do the following:

Select desired chart.
Click and drag the Color column from Data Pane to Filters on this visual in the Filter Pane.
Select the color you want to filter to.



Could you please show how the excel looks for this ?
The problem I have is that the field colour it is taking that as number so 3 colours present in that field red blue green but it shows in the filter 1 , 2 ,3 not the actual text

Can you please provide some sample data in your question? I will then edit this answer to match your data and show the steps to reproduce.
